# Some questions about making scalar product in latex

Tags: macros

I've just got registered here but I always read the site and I haven't found the answer for the following question. I just wanna make a specific view for scalar product. It should look like: . 
I use the following code:

`\newcommand*{\spr}{\left(\,#1\,|\,#2\,\right)}`.

The trouble is in this symbol: |.
The fact is that when I put on, e.g., \dfrac{}{} instead of expr1. or expr2., the height of that symbol is the same. How to make the height of "|" change with the changing of the heights of any of two expressions (before "|" and after "|")? 
Thank you for your attention and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question, a variable-sized pipe (i.e. `|`) can be obtained by replacing `|` with `\middle|`. Here is a MWE using `\dfrac`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\spr}[2]{\left(\,#1\,\middle|\,#2\,\right)}
\begin{document}

\(
  \spr{\dfrac{x}{y}}{z}
\)

\end{document}
```

Notice that your definition of `\spr` forgot to indicate that it takes two arguments. I have fixed that here. The code above gives the following output:

[image: variable-sized pipe]

Comment: Oh, yeah, thanks. Actually, I've made [2] but forgot to write down it here so, I'm sorry. Thank you. Also, if I'm not mistaken, it will always be "middle". That's not good if I put, for example, \dfrac into  \dfrac to the left side or, for example, just <a | z>.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by putting "\dfrac into \dfrac to the left side" or "<a | z>". Can you say more? Better yet, can you test the solution I posted and see whether it really doesn't work as you wish?

Comment: Sorry, sometimes I can't explain clearly haha. I mean, even if the expression on the left is too bulky the height of the "|" will stay middle anyway. Okay, I'll try your method, just later a little bit, when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, seriously, it works. God knows, why I didn't expect it to work. Thank you so much, @Simon C.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the macros from `mathtools` and `xparse`. I define a  `\spr` command with two arguments in one, separated by a comma. if one of the arguments is empty, it is replaced with a dot. To have variable sized parentheses or middle delimiter, use `\spr*`. You also can fine-tune  the size of the delimiters with an optional argument, which will be one of `big, \Big, \bigg` or `Bigg`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse, etoolbox}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\spr[1](){\sprargs{#1}}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\sprargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }
 {\sprargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\sprargsaux}{ m m }%
{\ifblank{#1}{\cdot}{#1}\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,\mathopen{}\ifblank{#2}{\cdot}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\[ \spr*{\dfrac{x}{y},z}\quad\spr[\Bigg]{\dfrac{x}{y},z}\quad\spr[\Big]{\dfrac{x}{y},z}\quad\spr*{,z} \quad\spr*{\dfrac{x}{y},} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]